# Getting SQLAlchemy to do "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" inside an ORM cascade (in MySQL)

Tags: python, mysql, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm cross posting this from the python reddit channel where i haven't managed to get a response on this yet. I'm surprised as this seems like an extremely standard scenario.

My question is whether there's an easy way to deal with primary key conflicts for a sub-object in a cascade insert in SQLAlchemy's ORM interface (on mysql). To give a specific example I have a sentence table and a "dictionary" table and when I create a sentence record I want to insert all the relevant words in the dictionary. Of course quite often some words will already be in the dictionary so I get a primary key error (the word is the key). If I was using raw SQL I'd do an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to get the id of the existing record and associate it with the sentence. I'd like to be able to do this in the ORM directly since the cascade is very convenient (the example above is actually simplified...there are many tables involved). Since the ORM does a cascade insert I don't even know how to control the inserts of the words in the dictionary.

This seems like a very standard problem but most responses I've seen don't use the ORM. I've seen a lot of related questions (about ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE) and the answer seems to be a custom @compiles like:

https://github.com/bedwards/sqlalchemy_mysql_ext/blob/master/duplicate.py

What I don't understand (as I'm still learning SQLAlchemy) is if this actaully can be used inside the ORM? If not is there another solution that can?

I already tried a session.merge() instead of a session.add() but that didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Thanks to iuridiniz's help below I can now provide some concrete code that demonstrates the problem.  Assume we have a table of Groups with a one-to-many relations to Users and each user has a one-to-one relation with (email)Addresses and the latter must be unique.  We can now create two users with the same address and if we directly do merge on the Users it behaves correctly (not throwing an error because of the duplicate email address).  But if we create two users with identical address then add them to a group and try to do a merge on the Group it will throw a unique key error (i.e. it does not check for the existence of an address before trying to add it):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, types
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)
Base = declarative_base()

session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = "groups"
    gid = Column(types.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(types.String(255))

    users = relationship("User", backref="group")

    def __repr__(self):
        ret =  "Group(name=%r)" % self.name
        for user in self.users:
            ret += str(user)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    login = Column(types.String(50), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(types.String(255))
    group_id = Column(types.Integer, ForeignKey('groups.gid'))
    address = Column(types.String(200), 
                            ForeignKey('addresses.email_address'))
    email = relationship("Address")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "User(login=%r, name=%r)\n%s" % (self.login, self.name,
                str(self.email))
```

Any thoughts on an elegant way to resolve this?

Sorry for the bad stack-overflow etiquette in using "answer" to originally post this edit.

Comment: I saw your update and I tested your code, but I think that it is a bug on sqlalchemy, could you post it [here](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/new)

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK SQLAlchemy ORM layer doesn't have a way to do an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. Fortunately the [`session.merge()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/session_state_management.html#merging) function can do this for you, but **only** if the key is a **primary key** (your case is).

`session.merge(o)` checks if a row with the same primary key value exists by issuing a `SELECT` and, if true, it issues an `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`.

See this example:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, types
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)
Base = declarative_base()
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    login = Column(types.String(50), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(types.String(255))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "User(login=%r, name=%r)" % (self.login, self.name)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create two users    
    u1 = User(login='iuridiniz', name="Iuri Diniz")
    u2 = User(login='someuser', name="Some User")
    session.merge(u1) # could be session.add(u1)
    session.merge(u2) # could be session.add(u2)
    session.commit()

    # print all users
    print("First two users")
    for u in session.query(User):
        print(u)

    # create more two users, one with the same login
    u3 = User(login='iuridiniz', name="Iuri Gomes Diniz")
    u4 = User(login='anotheruser', name="Another User")
    session.merge(u3) # session.add(u3) will raise a sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError
    session.merge(u4) # could be session.add(u4)
    session.commit()

    print("More two users")
    for u in session.query(User):
        print(u)
```

The output:

```
First two users
User(login=u'iuridiniz', name=u'Iuri Diniz')
User(login=u'someuser', name=u'Some User')
More two users
User(login=u'iuridiniz', name=u'Iuri Gomes Diniz')
User(login=u'someuser', name=u'Some User')
User(login=u'anotheruser', name=u'Another User')
```

Change `engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)` to `engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)` in order to view the queries executed:

```
[INFO Engine] SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
[INFO Engine] ()
[INFO Engine] SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
[INFO Engine] ()
[INFO Engine] PRAGMA table_info("user")
[INFO Engine] ()
[INFO Engine] 
CREATE TABLE user (
    login VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR(255), 
    PRIMARY KEY (login)
)


[INFO Engine] ()
[INFO Engine] COMMIT
[INFO Engine] BEGIN (implicit)
[INFO Engine] SELECT user.login AS user_login, user.name AS user_name 
FROM user 
WHERE user.login = ?
[INFO Engine] ('iuridiniz',)
[INFO Engine] INSERT INTO user (login, name) VALUES (?, ?)
[INFO Engine] ('iuridiniz', 'Iuri Diniz')
[INFO Engine] SELECT user.login AS user_login, user.name AS user_name 
FROM user 
WHERE user.login = ?
[INFO Engine] ('someuser',)
[INFO Engine] INSERT INTO user (login, name) VALUES (?, ?)
[INFO Engine] ('someuser', 'Some User')
[INFO Engine] COMMIT
[INFO Engine] BEGIN (implicit)
[INFO Engine] SELECT user.login AS user_login, user.name AS user_name 
FROM user 
WHERE user.login = ?
[INFO Engine] ('iuridiniz',)
[INFO Engine] UPDATE user SET name=? WHERE user.login = ?
[INFO Engine] ('Iuri Gomes Diniz', 'iuridiniz')
[INFO Engine] SELECT user.login AS user_login, user.name AS user_name 
FROM user 
WHERE user.login = ?
[INFO Engine] ('anotheruser',)
[INFO Engine] INSERT INTO user (login, name) VALUES (?, ?)
[INFO Engine] ('anotheruser', 'Another User')
[INFO Engine] COMMIT
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this helpful example.  I tried it but then managed to modify it to exhibit the problem I'm talking about (please see  my post below).